Put comma seperated data from one table into a new table as seperate rows
I'm trying to get a comma separated list of values from one table into a new table as separate rows. Without losing key-value relations.
Table 1 (original data)



key
values




key1
val1,val2,val3,val4


key2
val1,val2,val3,val4



Table 2 (new data)



key
value




key1
val1


key1
val2


key1
val3


key1
val4


key2
val1


key2
val2


etc...




I have no idea how to do this in MYSQL. Not a clue where to start or how to even Google it.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows

' how to even Google it' - search for mysql split string.

Does this answer your question? SQL split values to multiple rows

Here a sample for you. You can also found this by google
create a table like this
CREATE TABLE `tagstrings` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mykey` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mytags` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

fill it
INSERT INTO `tagstrings` (`id`, `mykey`, `mytags`)
VALUES
    (1, 'key1', 'Luke,Bernd,Paul'),
    (2, 'key2', 'Ann,Lisa'),
    (3, 'key3', 'Joe'),
    (4, 'key4', 'Robert,David,Axel,Frank');

SELECT it
SELECT * tagstrings;

1   key1    Luke,Bernd,Paul
2   key2    Ann,Lisa
3   key3    Joe
4   key4    Robert,David,Axel,Frank

query
SELECT t.mykey, tags.tag FROM tagstrings t
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REGEXP_REPLACE(mytags, ', *', '","'), '"]'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(tag VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')
) AS tags;

result
key1    Luke
key1    Bernd
key1    Paul
key2    Ann
key2    Lisa
key3    Joe
key4    Robert
key4    David
key4    Axel
key4    Frank


Try using string splitting functions along with a cross apply.
Like this.
INSERT INTO Table2 ([key], value) SELECT t1.[key], s.value FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.[values], ',') s;

MySQL <> SQL Server

ie there is no string_split function in mysql.
